# Secuirty Problems When Not Killing Session On Redirect to Public Page

Tags: asp.net, security, session

I'm developing a financal application such as online banking. I'm wondering what are the problems may arise when user browses a page that application does not include(e.g. google.com).

My Customer wants me not to kill the session so the user can return the application like facebook

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Online banking systems I know even kill the session if you use the browsers navigation functionality. I don't think this is essential, actually I think it's overkill. Killing the session when a user leaves your page (and don't forget it's not really secure, because you'll need JavaScript for this) might be ok. But the point is: It's only risky, if a user does not log out and leaves the PC, so somebody else could go on with his session. If it makes things more secure to abandon a session after leaving the page... hard to say. I don't think many people leave an online banking system with coming back soon in mind. So, I would suggest: log out the user (once again: you cannot guarantee because of JavaScript).

Update: Had an idea. You could use some serverside token that lets you know if a user navigated threw the pages nav or used the browsers nav or address bar. With this, you don't need JS and it's secure I think, but I'm not sure. I would ask google for best practices in such cases.

Comment: Thx for advice Linus. My situation is more complicated. Customer wants some information links below the online banking page. And says 'When user clicks one of the links , The page should navigate the links href. And when user navigates back he should continue the process where he was left. I could not convinced him. And he refuses the iframe option in online banking page